# Change text on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to create a menu system that changes text based on what menu has been clicked on at the time, as I don't want to create dozen of pages that will be almost identical and require loads of loading.
I've looked online but I haven't found anything, probably because I haven't used the right key words but I was wondering what the best approach would be to accomplish this? I've found that you can use the visibility tag in css to hide text but this leaves a lot of blank lines and since i'm displaying a lot of text it would look awful

HTML:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="accordian">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"></span>Menu 1</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><span class="icon-tasks"></span>Menu 2</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3><span class="icon-calendar"></span>Menu 3</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 9</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    background: #4EB889;
    font-family: Nunito, arial, verdana;
}
#accordian {
    background: #004050;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    color: white;
    box-shadow:
        0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
        0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#accordian h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #003040;
    background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
#accordian h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
#accordian h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#accordian li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#accordian ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
#accordian ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
#accordian ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#accordian li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Side note: If you want to not display an element on the page using CSS you can use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`. Visibility will still use the space that the element takes up but won't display any content, while display will neither use space nor display content.

Comment: This sounds like you need a Javascript JSON solution...not CSS.

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. I got it working by using an opentab function on the menu links and toggling display. Someone had suggested it but they seem to have deleted their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change css, try to use hide() and show()

[here is example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_show_hide)